# Variable name from template argument?

Tags: c++, templates, generics

Is there any way to generate the name of a variable inside a class based on a `template` argument?

```
template<class T, (someconstruct) t>

class Item {
    public:        
        T t;
};

Item<float, "Position"> myItem;

myItem.Position = 0.123f;
```

Such that what I have instantiated is a variable of type `T`, with the identifier `t` (where `t` is passed in by the programmer, i.e. `Position`, so we have a `T` called `Position`? Or is this stretching the template meta-programming concept a little too far? :p

Comment: 1. Propably not possible. 2. Propably a very broken idea. 3. Why do you think you need this? (4. The preprocessor can do this, but that's not an acceptable answer)

Comment: Let me guess: because he's former PHP programmer ;-)

Comment: Yes, I know it's obscure!  I'm implementing a generic templated vertex type, where each component of a vertex has both a type (i.e. float[3] or Vector3d - and a usage, i.e. usage_normal, usage_position, etc.  I'd like to be able to construct vertices by passing in template arguments and using template recursion to build a structure, in a similar way to this: http://www.entropygames.net/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=51:generic-vertices&catid=37:articles&Itemid=56

Comment: @Robinson, so why not use enums to represent usage?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish my comment... was fooled by pressing the enter button!  I'm recursively building a vertex structure from template arguments.  But using this method I can't have, say, two of the same enum "type" because the specialisation gives them the same identifier.

Comment: @Robinson, templates can also specialize by *value* - not just type. For example: `template <int N> struct Foo;`  As long as the value is an integral constant or enumeration type.  So if you had a "usage enum" called `Usage`, you could create a template like `template <Usage U> struct Foo;`, and then specialize it as you see fit for each enumerated type.

Comment: With reference to the URL you provided why can't you just have `template <> struct vertex_part<usage_normal_3f> { vector<float, 3> normal; };` alongside the specialisation for uasge_position_3f? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Robinson: I'd be interested in you opinion on the answer I provided.

Comment: Hey user, I will take a look at it in more detail later on.  I solved this little problem by completely changing my approach.  I have a variant structure that maps directly to an OpenGL/D3D vertex buffer and I store an array of these to make up a vertex.  All the meta-data is in the structure and the name is the string key (or index) in the array of meta- items.  This works OK because I don't need frequent low-level access to individual vertex components outside of shaders.  Might be a performance problem if I ever do though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't achieve this with templates.  Variable names (known as "identifiers") cannot be programatically manipulated by templates.  Only the [preprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) can do that.

Regardless, this seems like a bad idea.  Why do you *want* to do this?

Comment: Ok, as I suspected :(. Thanks Charles.

Answer (score 7):

No, not with that syntax, but you CAN create a setup similar to what you're trying to do:

```
template < typename Field >
struct field_value
{
  typename Field::type value;
};

template < typename Seq >
struct funky_struct : boost::mpl::inherit_linearly
  <
    Seq
  , boost::mpl::inherit
    <
      field_value< boost::mpl::placeholders::_2>
    , boost::mpl::placeholders::_1
    >
  >::type
{};

template < typename Field, typename Struct >
typename Field::type & get(Struct & s) { return static_cast< field_value<Field>& >(s).value; }

struct first_field { typedef int type; };
struct second_field { typedef char type; };

struct my_funky : funky_struct< boost::mpl::vector<first_field,second_field> > {};

...
my_funky f;
get<first_field>(f) = 23;
```

I leave allowing non-default construction to you.  Also, with a minor amount of work this can be reflected and you can stick any amount of useful information about fields within.

Comment: +1 I do something similar in a class I wrote which enumerates incoming message fields

Answer (score 5):

Something like what you want to achieve can be accomplished with inheritance. That is, the parent class has the variable name you want your template to have.

```
struct ItemNull {};

template <typename X, typename Y = ItemNull>
class Item : public X, public Y {};

template <typename T> struct HasPosition { T Position; };
template <typename T> struct HasMomentum { T Momentum; };

Item< HasPosition<float> > myItem1;
myItem1.Position = 0.123f;

Item< HasPosition<float>, HasMomentum<float> > myItem2;
myItem2.Position = 0.1f;
myItem2.Momentum = 0.2f;
```

The optional second argument allows for composition, as illustrated in `myItem2`. To add a third field, you could add to the tail, or expand from the front:

```
template <typename T> struct HasName { T Name; };

Item <
    HasPosition<float>,
    Item< HasMomentum<float>, HasName<std::string> >
> myItem3;
myItem3.Position = 0.1f;
myItem3.Momentum = 0.2f;
myItem3.Name = "Adam";

Item <
    Item < HasPosition<float>, HasMomentum<float> >,
    HasName<std::string>
> myItem4;
myItem4.Position = 0.1f;
myItem4.Momentum = 0.2f;
myItem4.Name = "Adam";
```

My personal preference is for the former of the two methods, because I find it to be a more intuitive way to extend it beyond 3 fields. The `Item` template syntax could probably be simplified using variadic template arguments.

The `Has...` templates could be machine generated or a macro could be created to make adding new fields a relatively simple task.

```
#define MAKE_HAS(X) template <typename T> struct Has##X { T X; }

MAKE_HAS(Position);
MAKE_HAS(Momentum);
MAKE_HAS(Name);
```